# numpy - multiply each element in array by a scaling factor

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array of values, and a list of scaling factors which I want to scale each value in the array by, down each column

```
values = [[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ],
          [ 1, 1, 4, 3 ],
          [ 2, 1, 6, 3 ],
          [ 3, 1, 8, 3 ]]
ls_alloc = [ 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2]

# convert values into numpy array
import numpy as np
na_values = np.array(values, dtype=float)
```

**Edit:** To clarify:

`na_values` can is a 2-dimensional array of stock cumulative returns (ie: normalised to day 1), where each row represents a date, and each column a stock. The data is returned as an array for each date.

I want to now scale each stock's cumulative return by its allocation in the portfolio. So for each date (ie: each row of `ndarray` values, apply the respective element from `ls_alloc` to the array element-wise)

```
# scale each value by its allocation
na_components = [ ls_alloc[i] * na_values[:,i] for i in range(len(ls_alloc)) ]
```

This does what I want, but I can't help but feel there must be a way to have **numpy do this for me automatically?**

That is, I feel:

```
na_components = [ ls_alloc[i] * na_values[:,i] for i in range(len(ls_alloc)) ]
# display na_components
na_components
[array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3]), \
 array([ 0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4]), \
 array([ 0.6,  1.2,  1.8,  2.4]), \
 array([ 0.6,  0.6,  0.6,  0.6])]
```

should be able to be expressed as something like:

```
tmp = np.multiply(na_values, ls_alloc)
# display tmp
tmp
array([[ 0. ,  0.4,  0.6,  0.6],
       [ 0.1,  0.4,  1.2,  0.6],
       [ 0.2,  0.4,  1.8,  0.6],
       [ 0.3,  0.4,  2.4,  0.6]])
```

Is there a numpy function which will achieve what I want elegantly and succinctly?

**Edit:**
I see that my first solution has transposed my data, such that I am returned a `list` of `ndarrays`. `na_components[0]` now gives an `ndarray` of the stock values for the first stock, 1 element per date.

The next step that I perform with `na_components` is to calculate the total cumulative return for the portfolio by summing each individual component

```
na_pfo_cum_ret = np.sum(na_components, axis=0)
```

This works with the list of individual stock return `ndarrays`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That order seems a little odd to me, but IIUC, all you need to do is to transpose the result of multiplying `na_values` by `array(ls_alloc)`:

```
>>> v
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  4.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  6.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  1.,  8.,  3.]])
>>> a
array([ 0.1,  0.4,  0.3,  0.2])
>>> (v*a).T
array([[ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3],
       [ 0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4],
       [ 0.6,  1.2,  1.8,  2.4],
       [ 0.6,  0.6,  0.6,  0.6]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear to me what you want to do, but the answer is probably in [Broadcasting rules](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-081b5e0ff3963e102f4bb39b39261750b507895e). I think you want:

```
values = np.array( [[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ],
                    [ 1, 1, 4, 3 ],
                    [ 2, 1, 6, 3 ],
                    [ 3, 1, 8, 3 ]] )
ls_alloc = np.array([ 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2])
```

and either:

```
na_components = values * ls_alloc
```

or:

```
na_components = values * ls_alloc[:,np.newaxis]
```